# Use only selected lines of `.bib` file

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am debugging a (very large) `.bib` file. To do so, I would like to read in chunks of the bib file at a time (say, the first n lines) while running the following source file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my-large-bib-file.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

I know I can just delete the last N lines and then paste in sections manually but is there a way to do that either through `biber` or through a command in the source file? I looked at section 3.7.1 of the `biblatex` documentation, but saw no pertinent option for `addbibresource` (or another command).

Comment: I'm not aware of any such option. It hardly makes sense in a productive situation. (You can be blissfully unaware *where* in your `.bib` file you have a particular entry, it only matters *that* it is there.) So it would only matter for debugging, where you have to do a lot by hand already. Also note that it would be dangerous to just cut the last $n$ lines, you need to make sure you don't slice an entry in halve, otherwise you'd leave a right mess.

Comment: biber (unlike bibtex) respects the standard %-comment char. So when I have to debug a bib-file, I add simply % before the entries I would like to hide.

Comment: Try debugging by entry type (an option to `\printbibliography`). However, I must say that Biber is usually remarkably good at helping you pinpoint the entry/entries that are a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer using `knitr`. It assumes that all entries' closing brace are on a line of their own. You may want to change the encoding settings if your bib file is written in UTF8.

```
<<>>=
n <- 1000
bib <- readLines("bibliography.bib", n = n)
while (tail(bib, 1) != "}"){
  n <- n + 1
  bib <- readLines("bibliography.bib", n = n)
}
writeLines(bib, "temp.bib")
@

\addtobibliography{temp.bib
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Many introductions to using LaTeX with long text suggest breaking the source up into parts and then including them into the 'master' document. The list of inclusions in the master can be variously commented in and out as need be. I've done just this for my own bib files, although in my case they were already broken up by subject. In your case, there are Unix commands that can break up a file into pieces (names vary). Find one of those and chop away!